# Open iOS app from Field Service Lightning mobile app

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, field-service-lightning

I require to open another app from FSL mobile app when someone clicks an URL on FSL Mobile Screen. for example, as how we open google maps for directions from yelp mobile app or browser etc.

Once I open the app, I also require to  pass parameters to another app over url from salesforce FSL.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

True.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using FSL App Extensions, which are triggered using the Action Button (circular lightning bolt button), and can pass parameters from the current record similar to a URL:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mfs_extension.htm&type=5